# How do I add a Dismissible Widget on my ListView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list View that I want to add a dismissible widget to. I want the item of the list View to disappear when clicked upon. I also want to eliminate the title of the entire list once all the elements of the list are over. 
Is it possible to make the ListTile disappear with the Dismissible widget or any other such widget?

This is the code of my list view:

```
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          'New User Tasks',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 26.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            fontFamily: "Netflix",
            color: Colors.orange,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )),

    SliverFixedExtentList(
      itemExtent: 80.0,
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          Divider(
            color: Colors.orange,
            height: 7.0,
          );
          ChatModel _model = ChatModel.dummyData[index];
          return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                if (index == 0) {
                  print('Hello');
                }
                if (index == 1) {
                  print('Helyyylo');

                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => SettingsView(),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                if (index == 2) {
                  print('Heooooo');
                }
              },
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Divider(
                    height: 4.0,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    leading: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                      child: Container(
                        // height:80,
                        // width:30,

                        child: Image.asset(_model.imagePath),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          _model.name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 17.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontFamily: "Netflix",
                            color: Colors.orange,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 16.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      _model.message,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        fontFamily: "Netflix",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        childCount: 3,
      ),
    ),
```

where:

```
class ChatModel {
  final String imagePath;
  final String name;
  final String datetime;
  final String message;

  ChatModel({this.imagePath, this.name, this.datetime, this.message});

  static final List<ChatModel> dummyData = [
    ChatModel(
      imagePath: 'assets/app/star1.jpg',
      name: "Rate Us",
      datetime: "20:18",
      message: "I love the app",
    ),
    ChatModel(
      imagePath: 'assets/app/test.jpg',
      name: "Invite Code",
      datetime: "19:22",
      message: "I love that idea, it's great!",
    ),
    ChatModel(
      imagePath: 'assets/app/share1.png',
      name: "First Poll Reward",
      datetime: "14:34",
      message: "I wasn't aware of that. Let me check",
    ),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the item on tap.

```
onTap: () {
 setState((){
   ChatModel.dummyData.removeAt(index);
 });
}
```